# Date range headache

Tags: django, django-models

```
#model
class Promotion(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    start_date = models.DateTimeField()
    end_date = models.DateTimeField()


#view
def promo_search(request):
    ...
    results = Promotion.objects.filter(start_date__gte=start_date).filter(end_date__lte=end_date)
    ...
```

(The code above obviously isn't going to work I'm just using it to 
help illustrate my problem.)

I want to show all active promotions between the start date and end 
date.

So if a promotion starts on 01/01/09 and ends 30/01/09 and a person 
searches from 01/12/08 to 01/02/09 it will still return a result. Also 
if they search from inside the date range e.g. 02/01/09 - 03/01/09 
they would get the same result.

Is there some magical django way of achieving this without looping 
over each day?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have four dates to consider: `start_search`, `end_search`, `start_promo` and `end_promo`.  You are looking for promotions where `start_promo <= end_search` and `end_promo >= start_search`:

```
results = Promotion.objects.\
            filter(start_date__lte=end_date).\
            filter(end_date__gte=start_date)
```